# Is δέ an adversative or copulative particle?

Tags: greek, conjunction

Is δέ an adversative or copulative particle?

<sup>This is the Greek analogue of my Latin question "[Is *autem* an adversative or copulative particle?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/6304/576)"</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple answer is *both.* Here is the outline of what [Perseus’ word study tool](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=%CE%B4%CE%AD&la=greek#lexicon) says:

> δέ , 
>  A. *but*: adversative and copulative Particle,
>   I. answering to μέν [... *(adversative)* ...]  
>   II. without preceding μέν,
>
> 1. adversative, expressing dist. opposition [...]
> 2. copulative, [...]
>
> [...]
>   B. POSITION of δέ [...] 
>   [...]

The fact is that we should accept these classifications *grano salis addito.* *Autem* is much stronger, δέ is much weaker, but they both escape our rigid grids. There isn’t an *adversative* δέ contrasted to a *copulative* one. There is only one δέ which occupies its own area of possible uses, happily ignoring the fact that some grammarians have drawn boundaries through that area. I’d say that *δέ adds new elements to the discourse.* Those new elements might be in sharp contrast to the old ones (a contrast possibly anticipated by μέν), or be simply a rather unexpected addition, or even be a consequence of the preceding material, provided that there is an element of novelty.

**Edit:** I would like to clarify that the “novelty” I am talking about has nothing to do with a linguistic analysis based on [topics and comments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_and_comment). Sometimes *comments* are referred to as *new information,* but in fact noun phrases marked with δέ are very often *topics.* When using the word “new”, I assume nothing about the theme-rheme structure of the sentence.

Comment: Just as a side note, "topic/comment" doesn't really map on to "old/new" -- you can have a topic that's new to the discourse.